# UIAlertController doesn't display and crashes/freezes app in iOS8

Tags: ios, ios8, unrecognized-selector, uialertcontroller

I am trying to create a button on my app that when pressed will ask the user whether or not they want to add a picture by taking it or by choosing an existing photo from their library. I have been searching all over for the past few days and I have pieced together this code from a few tutorials and some other questions asked on this site. I have this in Xcode and have it connected to a bottom bar button. When I run the simulator and press the button the app freezes or crashes. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
-(IBAction)showAlertAction:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertController * alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle: nil
                                                                              message: nil
                                                                       preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
    [alertController addAction: [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle: @"Take Photo" style: UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

        picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
        [self presentViewController: picker animated: YES completion:NULL];

    }]];
    [alertController addAction: [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle: @"Choose Existing Photo" style: UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

        picker2 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
        picker2.delegate = self;
        [picker2 setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
        [self presentViewController: picker2 animated: YES completion:NULL];

    }]];

    alertController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;

    UIView *senderView = (UIView *) sender;
    UIPopoverPresentationController * popover = alertController.popoverPresentationController;
    popover.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;
    popover.sourceView = senderView;
    popover.sourceRect = senderView.bounds;

    [self presentViewController: alertController animated: YES completion: nil];
}
```

Here is the error given in the debug section...

```
2015-07-08 10:37:13.162 LED Audit[6011:282032] -[UIBarButtonItem bounds]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b658770
2015-07-08 10:37:13.518 LED Audit[6011:282032] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIBarButtonItem bounds]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b658770'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x008b9746 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00542a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x008c1705 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00808287 ___forwarding___ + 1047
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x008baede __forwarding_prep_1___ + 14
    5   LED Audit                           0x000570ea -[PictureViewController showAlertAction:] + 1130
    6   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x005587cd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
    7   UIKit                               0x00c79a90 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 99
    8   UIKit                               0x00fffbba -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 139
    9   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x005587cd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
    10  UIKit                               0x00c79a90 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 99
    11  UIKit                               0x00c79a22 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 64
    12  UIKit                               0x00dba18a -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 69
    13  UIKit                               0x00dba5a7 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 598
    14  UIKit                               0x00db9811 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 660
    15  UIKit                               0x00cd1cfa -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 874
    16  UIKit                               0x00cd27d6 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 792
    17  UIKit                               0x00c906d1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    18  UIKit                               0x00ca0b08 _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 21484
    19  UIKit                               0x00c74337 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2300
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x007db06f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x007d0b7d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 253
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x007d00d8 __CFRunLoopRun + 952
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x007cfa5b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x007cf88b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x03b1f2c9 GSEventRunModal + 192
    26  GraphicsServices                    0x03b1f106 GSEventRun + 104
    27  UIKit                               0x00c78106 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    28  LED Audit                           0x00058d9a main + 138
    29  libdyld.dylib                       0x02c45ac9 start + 1
    30  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Can you post the output in the debugger console you get when you press your button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use a bar button item as a view, it is not. The fix is very simple.

```
UIPopoverPresentationController * popover = alertController.popoverPresentationController;
popover.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;
popover.barButtonItem = sender;
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem of my alert controller now displaying. However now the buttons aren't working and are crashing so there is some work to be done on the buttons. All in all though thank you!